# I have a Line 6 M5 Modeler and a distortion pedal. What would be the best way to get that dirty sexy blues sound in a slow tempo and minor key?

Tags: electric-guitar

I don't want it to sound heavily distorted.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a second to read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This question could be mistaken for "please recommend some gear," which is off-topic, or for the "how did so-and-so get that sound on that song" type of question, also off-topic. IMO it's actually a question about technique—"how do I do X," which can be on-topic. The problem is I'm not actually sure exactly what you're going for. Could you use the "edit" button to elaborate?

Comment: 'Blues' is a bit broad, covering a thousand acts over nearly 100 years. Personally, I'd say you don't need any kind of 'stomp box', just the amp & guitar.

Comment: It would also help to know what guitar you have. (Assuming you have one!)  Getting the sound you want depends on the pickups.  It also depends a lot on how you play.

Comment: @Tetsujin As in so many genres, it's not so much about the gear, as what you do with it!

Comment: @AndyBonner - Indeedy!. I have a 20-year-old amp modeller, Line6 UX2 [as simple as it gets compared to the newer stuff] & its 1960s Marshall does this without even thinking*. Sometimes add a very simple 'fuzz' box [still in modelling] for big, loud solos. Nothing else needed. I find most beginners start with far too much distortion, or too powerful a guitar or amp & wonder where all the dynamic & attack went. [*Comparatively, its 'modern' hi-gain Marshall sucks at it.]

Comment: We have to know which modeler and which distortion pedal you have. A Rat is totally different from an OCD, for example.